# Cómo saber dónde se instala una aplicación propia UWP en dispositivo windows 10 mobile enterprise

Tags: uwp

He creado una aplicación UWP para un dispositivo ARM que tiene el sistema operativo Windows 10 mobile entreprise y la he instalado de forma correcta.
Pero quiero saber en que ruta se ha instalado para poder modificar un archivo json.

Un saludo y gracias

Comment: puedes validar la ruta de instalacion desde el `acceso directo->click derecho->propiedades-> abrir ubicacion`
si se auto agrega al path con el comando `where nombreDelEjecutable` desde una consola cmd.

Comment: El dispositivo es un móvil, no tengo click derecho. Si mantengo presionado con el dedo sobre el icono de la aplicación salen salen las opciones de "Anclar a inicio" y "Desinstalar".

Answer (score 0):

Desde el dispositivo no se puede acceder al sistema de archivos por seguridad.Sólo a algunas carpetas típicas.

Al final mediante programación obtuve la ruta de instalación de la aplicación pero a esa ruta luego desde el dispositivo no se puede acceder por seguridad.